# -webkit-clip-path mysterious line in chrome when scrollbar present

Tags: css, google-chrome

When using `-webkit-clip-path` in Google Chrome to create an angled border effect, a mysterious sliver of the equal width background element is visible only when the scrollbar is present.

**With scrollbar:**

[image]

**Without scrollbar:**

[image]

I can't see anything in the computed styles that would cause this. Is there a way I can consistently achieve the desired look (without the line)? Preferably without using some pseudo/absolute positioned element to hide it.

**The Code (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKmYgP):**

```css
.container {
  background: #ff0000;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  background: #fff;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 20%, 100% 0px, 100% 100%, 0px 100%)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide this line by using the following snippet.

```css
.container {
  background: #ff0000;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  background: #fff;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 20%, calc(100% + 1px) 0px, calc(100% + 1px) 100%, 0px 100%);
  
  /** or this... 
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 20%, 101% 0px, 101% 100%, 0px 100%);
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

If you remove the `margin:0 auto;` of `.container` the line disappears too (without changes on `-webkit-clip-path`)!

**Explanation:**
The `auto` value on `margin` create this red line, because the right margin is a floating number like `0.5px`. But Google Chrome can't draw a half line. So the margin get rounded down to the next, not floating value `0.0px` and the `.container` get stretched. Other Browser round up to `1.0px` and the line doesn't appear.

**The outside of the container looks like this:**

```css
.container {
  background: #ff0000;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  background: #fff;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 20px, 100px 0px, 100px 100px, 0px 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

So you see `1px` of the red area on the right side!